Binomial test for 1:1 ratio (Python)
I have collected data on gender ratios that looks like this:
These are counts. I evaluated 100 employees from each company, each department. And then evaluated whether they're Male or Female.
                Company A            Company B           Company C
Department      Female   Male        Female   Male       Female   Male
Arts            98       2           95       5          80       20
Engineering     2        98          30       70         10       90
Housekeeping    100      0           90       10         70       30

Now, my teacher has asked to do a Binomial test (followed by a Chi-square test) to determine whether the gender ratio is different from 1:1 to a statistically significant level. How can I do this in Python?
I have tried reading about the concept here:
https://www.ncl.ac.uk/webtemplate/ask-assets/external/maths-resources/statistics/hypothesis-testing/hypothesis-testing-with-the-binomial-distribution.html
but I am not sure how exactly to implement it and which variables to use where. Since I have 3 different variables: gender, company name, and department. Or should I skip the departments and do a general ratio comparison between different companies?
I'm guessing there can be several different ways here so I am open to suggestions.
So my hypothesis was that the gender ratio is not 1:1. It deviates. But I guess what my teacher is asking to evaluate is that is the ratio significantly skewed? I guess the definition of "significantly skewed" is up to me so perhaps I could say that 1:1 is okay but 3:1 is too bad. But I don't know how to use a binomial test to on this data to actually draw any conclusions
